# Execute all indices in Kubernetes Indexed job even after some indices fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubernetes jobs API has support for back-off limit, which is global to all indices.
However, in the case of indexed jobs, I want to be able to continue executing the other indices even after some indices fail.
Since the back-off limit is global once a certain number of failures was reached the job is marked as failed and the other indices are not run.
How can I configure the Kubernetes job to attempt to run all indices?